# Ordenar select Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, sql

Buen día amigos tengo una duda al yo hacer el siguiente query[image: Este query]

Como resultado obtengo esto
[image: resultado]

¿Hay alguna manera de traer los datos con el orden en que se hizo la consulta? Es decir  primero los datos del Id 1, luego los del 3, y por último los del 2? Algo así[image: O simplemente no se puede]
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con esta consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM fotos WHERE Id IN (1,2,3) ORDER BY FIELD(Id,1,3,2);
```

Puedes optar por una informacion mas detallada [ver aqui](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109120/how-does-order-by-field-in-mysql-work-internally)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, me funcionó perfecto!